# Use of 'here' for an army in Modern English

Tags: old-english, military

I came upon that *here* used to be utilised for an army (more likely enemy) in Old English (also shown in [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/here#Old_English)). The same page also shows that there is a modern form of the word as *here* and that it could be used for an army. However, obviously such behaviour is uncommon (Google usage stats would reflect the more common adverb hence I didn't try using that to check investigate this).

Does anyone know or can think of a modern situation where this usage has happened? Alternatively, why has this specific usage of *here* diminished?

Comment: The word is obsolete in Modern English. Whoever made the Wiktionary entry just forgot to mark that; I have edited it to add the "obsolete" tag. No one except an Old English professor would understand it if you used "here" to refer to an army.

Comment: It was Old English. It disappeared, carried away with much of its native lexicon, survived by adopted words from French and Latin. The cognate still exists in German; it's the root for _Herr_, which was originally a military term, like all feudal titles. Oh, and the OE _here_ was pronounced "heh-reh", with two syllables. No silent letters.

Comment: In addition to what @John says, it may be added that unlike in English, this word has survived as the common word (or one of the common words) for an army in several other Germanic languages: German _Heer_, Danish/Norwegian _hær_, Icelandic _her_, Faeroese _herur_. Like in English, though, Dutch _heer/heir_ is archaic and not generally used. See also Wiktionary’s article on [_*harjaz_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/harjaz), the reconstructed Proto-Germanic ancestral form of the word.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, That's actually why I started thinking about the question other than the OE note: German and Austrian standard usage is _Heer_, hence I thought it was quite curious. But I guess they have had less French and Latin influence perhaps... Wonder if Chaucer using it (not that I am 100% confident he didn't) would have made a difference?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Oxford English Dictionary*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/86139?result=2&rskey=ohLWAj&) has marked this definition of "here" as *obsolete*.  They describe their rationale for obsolete words as:

> If an entry, sense, or lemma is no longer in use in the English language, it may be considered obsolete. **This usually means that no evidence for the term can be found in modern English.** The latest quotation indicates the period when the term was last in use.

The latest source OED cited of "here" as standard, meaning an army, is from 1508.

> The tothir knightis maid care of arthuris here.

They also include one use from 1872 but the use is archaic in context.  It is used in a historical essay, knowingly using an antiquated term:

> Over 35 men (or 3 × 12) constituted a *Here* by Ini's laws.

So the expert opinion is that this term is obsolete and no longer in use in Modern English.

Why the term fell out of favor is a complicated question; The English language is fluid, new words are constantly entering the language and antiquated ones get left behind.  There are many entries in OED marked as "obsolete," by virtue of the constantly changing nature of the English language.

Comment: Thanks. The 1872 entry is a curious one: I only noticed it due to similar usage in an Osprey book from the last decade where it was talking about _herepath_ and the _fyrd_ vs _here_ difference: in some certain circles then, the scholarly usage of the term isn't unfamiliar. However, at the same time a recent Anglo-Saxon anthology I read never made mention of it though it covered a number of legal codices.